# Data from a form don't register in a database (Yii framework)

Tags: php, yii

I have view:

```
...
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content'); ?>
                <?php $this->widget('application.extensions.ckeditor.CKEditor',array( 
                        'model'=>$model, 
                        'attribute'=>'content', 
                        'language'=>'en', 
                        'editorTemplate'=>'full',)); 
                ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'content'); ?>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'status'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'status', array('0' => 'Not published', '1' => 'Published')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'status'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php
            echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id');
            echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_id','', Category::allCategory(),
                array(
                'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST', //request type
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('subcategory/dynamicSubCategories'), //url to call.
                //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
                'update'=>'#subcategory_id', //selector to update
                //'data'=>'js:javascript statement'
                //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
            )));
           echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); 
        ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php
            echo $form->labelEx($model,'subcategory_id');
            echo CHtml::dropDownList('subcategory_id','', array());
            echo $form->error($model,'subcategory_id');
        ?>
        </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
...
```

Data from the fields 'category_id' and 'subcategory_id' don't write in a database. All other fields successfully register. Prompt as me to tie this field to a form and to solve the matter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is because the data that is saved, should be part of the models array data, so change your new field name to reflect `MODELNAME[ATTRIBUTENAME]`

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('MODELNAME[category_id]', ...
```

or simply change to [activeDropdownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail)

Comment: You are upvote your answers from other account, it's not smart

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Yn87cJJU SubcategoryController.php, http://pastebin.com/R93qXAaq _ form. I have a problem. I edited a code, but AJAX ceased to work for me. Situation such when I choose value in the first dropDownList at me automatically data from a database are loaded into the second dropDownList. Now all this doesn't work. Prompt that I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for dropDownLists

```
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'category_id',Category::allCategory()
....
```

Or better use form method

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'category_id', Category::allCategory()
....
```

Comment: you were talking about model rules!

Comment: But then i saw there is other mistakes. And it's not copy, your answer  with MODELNAME[ATTRIBUTENAME] is a bit of silly.

Comment: I changed code http://pastebin.com/J3SkaneJ but I have an error. What I did wrong?

Comment: Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

...\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php(2053)